# Register custom select component using react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form

/*Custom component for select*/

```
  /* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import Image from "next/image";
import Select from "react-select";
import { forwardRef } from "react";

import ArrowDown from "../../assets/arrow_down.svg";

const CustomSelect = forwardRef(
  ({ value, options, onChange, placeholder, style }) => {
    return (
      <div className="relative">
        <div className="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center px-2 pointer-events-none z-10">
          <Image src={ArrowDown} alt="ArrowDown" width={16} height={16} />
        </div>
        <Select
          value={value}
          onChange={onChange}
          options={options}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          isSearchable={false} // Disable text input
          isClearable={true} // Enable the clearable feature
          styles={{
            control: (provided) => ({
              ...provided,
              paddingLeft: "1.2rem", // Adjust the padding to accommodate the icon width
            }),
            indicatorSeparator: () => null, // Hide the separator line
            dropdownIndicator: () => ({
              display: "none", // Hide the dropdown indicator arrow
            }),
            menu: (provided) => ({
              ...provided,
              backgroundColor: "#E3F0FC", // Change the background color here
              zIndex: 9999, // Add a z-index to the menu
            }),
            option: (provided) => ({
              ...provided,
              fontSize: "16px", // Change the font size to 16px
              fontWeight: 400, // Change the font weight to 400 (normal)
              color: "#1A1C1E", // Change the font color to #1A1C1E
            }),
          }}
          className={`${style}`}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
);

export default CustomSelect;
```

/*Form Component*/

```
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import CustomSelect from "../Select/Select";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

const Form = () => {
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState(null);

const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    reset,
    control,
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      CustomSelect: "",
      select: {},
    },
  });

  const [successMsg, setSuccessMsg] = useState("");

  const onSubmitted = (data, e) => {
    console.log(data);
    reset();
  };

  const handleSelectUser = (option) => {
    setSelectedUser(option);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitted)}>
        <div className="p-3">
          <Controller
            name="customSelect"
            control={control}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <CustomSelect
                {...field}
                options={claimTypeOptions}
                value={selectedUser}
                onChange={handleSelectUser}
                placeholder="Select an option"
              />
            )}
          />
          {errors.CustomSelect && errors.CustomSelect.type === "required" && (
            <p>mali</p>
          )}
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

I've been reading the documentation of react-hook-form. I've already tried in a normal inputs and select. however when i tried using custom components i'm experiencing issue. here in the code i'm trying to console the data that i'm getting in the customSelect component when the form is submit. however in the onSubmitted function the console log only displays this:

```
  CustomSelect
: 
""
customSelect
: 
undefined
select
: 
{}
```

I just want help in this. Am i using the Controller wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom select component is not correctly interfacing with the `Controller` from `react-hook-form`.

1. Make sure the name you pass to the `Controller` matches the name you expect in your form data. In your `Form` component, the name `customSelect` should be consistent everywhere.
2. Ensure that the `onChange`, `onBlur`, and `value` props from the field object provided by the `Controller`'s `render` prop are correctly passed to your `CustomSelect` component.
3. Your `CustomSelect` component should call the `onChange` prop with the new value whenever a new option is selected.

Here is how you can adjust the `CustomSelect`:

```
const CustomSelect = forwardRef(
  ({ value, options, onChange, onBlur, placeholder, style }, ref) => {
    // Note the inclusion of onBlur and ref in the props

    const handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
      onChange(selectedOption); // Pass the selected option to react-hook-form
    };

    return (
      <div className="relative">
        {/* ... */}
        <Select
          ref={ref}
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange} // Use the new local handleChange function
          onBlur={onBlur} // Pass onBlur to Select
          options={options}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          // ... other props and styles
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
);

export default CustomSelect;
```

And the `Form`:

```
const Form = () => {
  // ...

  const onSubmitted = (data) => {
    console.log(data); // Now it should log the correct value
    // ...
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitted)}>
        <div className="p-3">
          <Controller
            name="customSelect" // Make sure this name matches your `defaultValues`
            control={control}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <CustomSelect
                {...field} // Pass the field props directly
                options={claimTypeOptions}
                placeholder="Select an option"
              />
            )}
          />
          {errors.customSelect && <p>Error message for customSelect</p>}
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Comment: Thanks mate. it works now. but i have a few questions. I've already matched the default values to the "name"  in the Controller. however i've tested submitting the form to show the error message but it doesnt display:

{errors.customSelect && <p>Error message for customSelect</p>}

i have tried logging the errors in a console but it just shows empty object

Comment: Have you set up validation rules for `customSelect` in the `useForm` hook?

Comment: const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    reset,
    control,
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      customSelect: "",
    },
  });

is this what you're referring to?

Comment: // In your Form component
<Controller
  name="customSelect"
  control={control}
  rules={{ required: "This field is required" }} // Add validation rules here
  render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => (
    <CustomSelect
      {...field}
      options={claimTypeOptions}
      placeholder="Select an option"
    />
  )}
/>
{errors.customSelect && <p>{errors.customSelect.message}</p>}

Comment: If you think this is the answer for your question, Please make it as the answer. It'll help me very much! I am happy your issue got resolved

Comment: Hi bro, Can i still ask a question?

Comment: yes, go ahead..

Comment: May I know when to use a register and a controller in a component? Because now im trying to use react-hook-form in input component. but experiencing issues when using it in a controller